# Substituting data using multiple conditions

Tags: r, data-science

I am trying to replace values of a column observation, given a set of conditions. The data is as given:

```
Sex     Age
male    34.5
female  NA
male    62
male    NA
```

I am I want to replace the data where the sex is female and the age value is NA by a value.

I am currently using the for loop as:

```
for(i in 1:length(data$Sex){
     if(data$Sex[i]=="male"){
        if(is.na(data$Age[i])){
            data$Age[i] <- 30.7
        }
    }
 }
```

and this work perfectly fine. I was curious if I got it right or is there a computationally easier method to get this right.

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Your code modifies the value if `male` is true, but in your question, you say that you want to replace `NA` when the `Sex` is `female`. And yes, there is an easier way: you could create a boolean condition that checks for both at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 data[data$Sex=='female' & is.na(data$Age),'Age']<-30.7
```

Comment: If you want to understand what's happening here read up on subsetting with assignment. For example http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subassignment

Comment: Thank you, Shenglin Chen, I tried using the code before but don't know what went wrong. Works perfectly for now. The link is a great read.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace "female" as described in the text (rather than "male" as done in your code):

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Age = if_else(Sex == "female" & is.na(Age), 30.7, Age))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     Sex   Age
   <chr> <dbl>
1   male  34.5
2 female  30.7
3   male  62.0
4   male    NA
```

Comment: Thank you! the code works perfectly fine. And the replacement was for either Male or Female as I wanted to work with both.

Comment: Glad I could be of help